# Webview not re-sizing on orientation change

Tags: android, webview, resize, orientation

When my phone loads a story, it displays it nice and pretty, but once it is turned landscape there is a lot of extra white space inside of the webview. No matter what I have tried to do, I can't seem to remove them. From what I can tell, the height is not readjusting when the orientation is changed. I manage my own orientations, and everything seems to re-size properly, just not this one webview.

```
protected void displayStory()
{


    //FontSize();
    // TODO Display Stories
    art_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_title);
    art_title.setText(articleTitle);
    art_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    art_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_author);
    art_author.setText(articleAuthor + " | " + articleDate);
    art_author.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    web = new WebView(this);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);

    web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(14);
    //web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false); 
    web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    //web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", articleContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    web.loadData(articleContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    //FontSize();

}//end displayStory


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //setContentView(R.layout.pm_article);
    //web.clearView();
    //web = null;
    //displayStory();
    ads();
```

My xml looks like

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#86a6b2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sm_section"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:text="Author"
                android:textColor="#d2d2d2"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="#d2d2d2"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/WebView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#b6fcd5"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewLandAd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/WebView01"
            android:background="#d3414a"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/webViewLandAd"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sm_section"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="openComments"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Pamplin Media Group"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.portlandtribune.pamplinmediagroup.PM_article"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pm_article" >
```

Here are screenshots of what is going on.

This is when the phone is in portrait mode. The text is displayed as it should be. 
[image]

And when the phone is in landscape. The bottom of the webview is just blank text.
[image]

Comment: I'm also experiencing that same problem.